# Is one player better or just lucky?

Tags: probability

Two players play 100 games of pool. The first player wins 57 games and the second wins the rest. The second player declares he is just as good as the first despite the result which he claims was luck. How likely is the second players claim?

I simplify this down to a binomial and just add up all the probabilities from 57 to 100.

$\sum _{k=57}^{100} \binom{100}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100-k} \approx .09667395$

so there is a almost a 10% chance that this would happen by luck. Two other people using a formula from this wiki page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair

got a probability of .0816. Both of them used formulas they claimed were for continuous distributions. I do not see how this is a continuous distribution. I think their answer is an approximation of the discrete one I gave but they insist it is exact?! Who is closer to the truth my .0966739 or their .0816?

Comment: I have not checked your computation. Wolfram Alpha will do the summation without breaking a sweat. One can use the normal approximation to the binomial. But that would be an approximation only. Your expression is exact. Technically one is testing the null hypothesis $H_0$ that the players are equally matched against the alternate hypothesis that the person who got $57$ is "better." At the $5\%$ significance level, one would not reject $H_0$.

Comment: **Remark:** If we use the binomial model, we have to assume independence. The independence assumption may not be correct. Among very good players, the first has an advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the model you are using. On tossing a coin 2n times, in an ideal case you get n heads, but you can find the probability distribution of any number of tosses. You have used the binomial distribution. As the number of tosses increases, the distribution tends to be normal. I guess the wiki article does so. So it depends whether for the n you are considering, whether the distribution is more binomial or normal.